# How can I remove the write protection of a Word Document in C++?

Tags: c++, docx

I am copying a Word-document from a Server into my `%localappdata%\temp`-Directory. But the Document is write-protected, and I can't modify or delete it. I don't want to manually remove the protection, it needs to get done automatically

My code to copy and remove the protection is

```
CopyFile(strTemplate, userTempDir, TRUE);
        SetFileAttributesA(userTempDir, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
```

`strTemplate` is the PathToFile on the Server, `userTempDir` is the PathToFile to the copy directory (in this case "%localappdata%\temp\copy.doc")

But

```
SetFileAttributesA(userTempDir, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
```

doesn't work. I'm pretty new to C++ so I don't know how to remove that Write-Protection

Comment: What kind of write protection is it? Filesystem (NTFS) protection or application (MS Word) protection?

Comment: The Document itself is protected, so application

Comment: So, you must dig into the docx file format. If it was as easy as removing the file system attribute, it would have no meaning as a protection. Note that this is not related to C++, but to the file format Word uses.

Comment: This isn't a C++ question, it's a document file-format question. When you know how the protection works in the first place, you _may_ have a C++ question about how to _implement_ your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SetFileAttributes(userTempDir, GetFileAttributes(userTempDir) &~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
```

This will remove the Readonly Attribute, if there is one